# stdout redirection does not work if stdout is a file

Tags: c, posix, stdout, io-redirection

I am using code like the following to redirect stdout before calling a noisy function from an external library written in Fortran:

```
// copy standard output
out = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);

// close standard output
close(STDOUT_FILENO);

// use log file as standard output
log = open(log_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if(log != STDOUT_FILENO)
    fprintf(stderr, "could not create log file %s", log_file);

// call the library function that uses a lot of printf
func();

// restore original standard output
dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);

// close copy of standard output
close(out);
```

To summarise my intention of the above code snippet: copy stdout, close stdout (frees file descriptor 0), open file (uses lowest file descriptor = 0 = stdout), run code with redirected stdout, and reset stdout.

This works perfectly well when I run my code using the terminal as stdout. However, when I set stdout to a file (using `$ mycode > myfile.txt`) the redirection fails, and I end up with the output of `func()` in `myfile.txt` instead of the log file. How is this possible?

Comment: I have reduced this to a minimal test case, and the problem does not show. This leads me to believe it might be an artefact of the Fortran/C interaction. Is it possible to Fortran buffers the output somehow, and that it gets written to stdout after it has been reset? But then, why does it not get mixed up with the subsequent output from C?

Comment: If Fortran is buffering output, it's possible it's using the same buffers as C's `fwrite()`.  It's also possible the C runtime or your helper library is flushing Fortran's buffers when your C code tries to write to stdout.

Comment: Can you try `fflush(stdout)` before you restore the original stdout?

Comment: You might want to use `dup2()` to put the file descriptor from the log file in the right place since it's not guaranteed that the file will end up getting file descriptor `STDOUT_FILENO`.

Comment: @FUZxxl The definition of `open` says _"The open() function shall return a file descriptor for the named file that is the lowest file descriptor not currently open for that process."_ Since 0 was recently freed, it will be 0.

Comment: I should also add that I actually check that the opened file descriptor is equal to STDOUT_FILENO.

Comment: @njt `STDOUT_FILENO` is equal to 1 according to POSIX. Your program might run with closed standard input.

Comment: @FUZxxl You're right of course, I meant to write 1, not 0. In the code, I am using STDOUT_FILENO and not the numerical values.

Comment: @njt What I try to say is that your code will probably fail every time somebody starts it with closed standard input (which isn't all that uncommon). Using a `dup2()` approach is probably better.

Comment: @FUZxxl Oh I see, thanks for the heads-up. I modified my code accordingly. Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do `fflush(stdout)` before you restore the original stdout with `dup2`.

The reason it works with a terminal is because stdout is line buffered for a terminal.  So your output gets flushed immediately to the redirected file.  But when you start your program with stdout to a file, stdout becomes fully buffered, so your `func` output will be in a buffer waiting to be flushed.  When you restore the original stdout without flushing, the output gets written to the original stdout when the program exits.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of stdout's buffering, this explains the observed behaviour. I have now unsuccessfully tried `fflush(stdout)` and `fflush(log)` (after opening the log file with `fopen()`). I will also try to call Fortran's `FLUSH` if that's somehow possible.

Comment: Using a simple `fprintf(stderr, "waiting\n"); fflush(stderr); sleep(1000);` at the end of my code, I could see that in fact nothing gets written until the program exits. So by the time the Fortran output is flushed from the buffers, stdout has long been reset to its original state. I will mark this as the accepted answer since it has explained the observed behaviour.

Comment: A workaround that I found to produce the desired result is this: The problem is that whatever remains in Fortran's buffer at the end of the program will be written to the original stdout. So before I terminate, I now redirect back to the log file, so that the last part of the redirected output is written there as well.