# Why printf() does not output to a file, when stdout is redirected to that file?

Tags: c

The following is a simple `C` program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        while (1)
        {
                printf("Hello World\n");
                sleep(1);
        }
}
```

Build and run it, the "`Hello World`" will be printed in the terminal:

```
$ ./a.out
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

But if the `stdout` is redirected to a file, after running a while, there is still nothing in the file:

```
$ ./a.out > log.txt
^C
$ cat log.txt
$
```

Why doesn't the `printf` output to the file which `stdout` is redirected to?

Comment: It certainly does, but you aren't flushing it.

Comment: Line-buffering (thus, flushing every line) or outright unbuffered content is automatic on many platforms going to a TTY, but not going to a file.

Comment: "Ctrl + C" also not flush?

Comment: Correct, sending a SIGTERM does not cause an automatic flush.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Internals.html#Termination-Internals for glibc's documentation on this point. To quote: *Note that streams are not flushed automatically when the process terminates; see I/O on Streams.*

Comment: Change your loop to something like `for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { printf("Hello World\n"); }` and see what happens without the `ctrl-C`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will data written via write() be flushed to disk if a process is killed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647997/will-data-written-via-write-be-flushed-to-disk-if-a-process-is-killed)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy actually, my doubt is why line-buffering isn't applicable to file. Seems a little weird.

Comment: @NanXiao, because generally, with file I/O, the goal is to make throughput as high as possible. Splitting things up into lots of small writes instead of a few big ones tends to interfere with that.

Comment: @NanXiao, ...and in the case of a SIGTERM, if the user wants a program to exit, then presumably they (1) want it to finish exiting as soon as possible (not waiting for a potentially long time to flush buffers), and (2) don't care about its output (because if they want the output, why are they terminating it early?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Very clear explanations, resolve all my confusions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stdout redirection does not work if stdout is a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196939/stdout-redirection-does-not-work-if-stdout-is-a-file)

Comment: printf() does actually write, but an internal buffer has to fill before it goes to the disk. If you wait long enough before you kill your program, you will see something in the file.

Comment: Precede the command with stdbuf: `stdbuf -oL ./a.out > log.txt` to get line buffering.

Answer (score 3):

For terminal only by default it is line buffer. In here you redirected the stdout to the file. So, now the stdout is not pointing a terminal. It pointing a file. For the file it is by default fully buffered. So, you have flush the stdout after writing it.

Refer the answer for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196939/stdout-redirection-does-not-work-if-stdout-is-a-file).

As @js1, said, you have to call fflush(stdout) after writing it.